# Any way to change a workflow StatusCode?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

According to dynamics SDK :

> The previous operations can also be performed by using the Execute
>   method with the appropriate request messages. **Attributes of
>   AsyncOperation other than AsyncOperation.StateCode and
>   AsyncOperation.PostponeUntil should be considered read-only.**

Anyway to bypass those read-only?

I have a workflow with a StateCode = "Suspended" and a StatusCode = "Waiting".
I want to change the StatusCode to "Cancelled".

If I simply try to update StatusCode to "Cancelled", it just doesn't save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply changed the StateCode from **Suspended** to **Terminated**. The **StatusCode** is the automatically updated to **Cancelled**.